# Showing Images with carousel effect in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-gallery

[image: Carousel]

Hi I want to have image gallery like this.I have tried using [jazzyviewpager](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager).It's good but doesn't have this effect. can anybody tell me how can i achieve this effect for showing images.

Comment: this link will have the tutorial for 3d Android carousel http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the gallery view class, use setStaticTransformationsEnabled(true) and handle item transformations by yourself in getChildStaticTransformation .

EDIT: One way to do achieve this goal, is available in as a sample in a tutorial I wrote, here: http://code.google.com/p/android-3d-carousel-view/ . However this is not exactly what you need, just a starting point that you can modify further on. The important aspect is to learn how to use getChildStaticTransformation  .

Comment: @randhoo GalleryView is depricated!. can you provide me code snippet?

Comment: I have a code sample available on google code. If you are interested I can edit the answer to include the link.

Comment: I just added the link . Good luck with your project